# An equivalent of Looking Glass where VM side runs Linux?

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, gpu, gpu-passthrough

[Looking Glass](https://looking-glass.io/) is an open source application that allows the use of a KVM configured with a passthrough GPU without an attached physical monitor, keyboard or mouse.

In Looking Glass terminology, the *host software* is the term for the piece of Looking Glass that runs in the VM *guest* (the VM where the GPU is used). The *client software* is the term for the piece that runs on the Linux *host*, showing the rendered frames.

The Looking Glass host is currently Windows-only, and covers the main use case: run Windows-only GPU-heavy software in a Windows VM, showing the result on the Linux host.

I have a slightly different use case: I pass my beefier headless GPU through from a Linux host to a *Linux* VM guest. It works fine there for GPU computations based on OpenCL or CUDA or whatever. I'd also like to be able to run 3D software on that Linux VM guest, and display the result on my Linux host.

Thus: Is there an equivalent technology for a Linux guest on a Linux host? Or, alternatively, are there any Looking Glass hosts for Linux?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am the Author of Looking Glass.

The project already has Linux guest support as the host application is agnostic and can be built for both. Please note though that the support for the Linux guest is currently lacking features such as cursor support, etc.

Comment: That seems fantastic! Is this documented somewhere? The webpage still says that Windows 10 is the only supported guest OS. I don't wanna turn the comment field into a chat, but are there some notes somewhere that I could take a look at in order to get started with this?

Comment: windows host is the only supported guest OS simply due to not having an active dev working on the Linux host. I simply do not have time to support both platforms but put enough of the framework there if someone were to get invovled.

Comment: I understand. But is your comment saying the opposite of your answer? I'm confused.

And is anything written down about the Linux-Linux combo anywhere?

Comment: Developer support != Software support. The software has partial support but at the moment there is no active maintainer for the Linux host application. If you want to know more please join the LG Discord Server, which is the place to discuss these things.

Comment: Ah, sorry, my bad. I was misreading you. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score -1):

While not a shared memory device solution, one option for getting great performance and accelerated graphics from headless cards on Linux is to use [NoMachine](https://www.nomachine.com/). In my opinion NoMachine works better than other solution like RDP and VNC, and has support most devices Linux/MacOS/Windows/Android etc...

To use acceleration with NVIDIA's headless Tesla card for example and support your CUDA apps, install the NVIDIA driver first and then use [these instructions from VirtualGL for configuring Xorg to use a headless card](https://virtualgl.org/Documentation/HeadlessNV).

Run `nvidia-xconfig --query-gpu-info` to obtain the bus ID of the GPU. Example:

```
GPU #0:
  Name      : Tesla M60
  ...
  PCI BusID : PCI:136:0:0
```

Create an appropriate `xorg.conf` file for headless operation:

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig -a --allow-empty-initial-configuration --use-display-device=None --virtual=1920x1200 --busid {busid}
```

Replace `{busid}` with the bus ID you obtained in Step 1. Leave out `--use-display-device=None` if the GPU is headless, i.e. if it has no display outputs.
If you are using version 440.xx or later of the NVIDIA proprietary driver, then edit `xorg.conf` and add `Option "HardDPMS" "false"` under the Device- or Screen -section.

Then install NoMachine and if you run `nvidia-smi` you should see Xorg is running on the NVIDIA GPU.
If you don't want to use NoMachine Your other option is to use [VirtualGL](https://www.virtualgl.org/) with [xrdp](http://xrdp.org/), VNC, or [xpra](https://xpra.org). and launch your desktop with `vglrun` , for example `vglrun xfce4-session` which I use, but YMMV using other desktops.

If you don't need CUDA apps, I've had luck getting the Open Source driver **nouveau** working out of box accelerating NoMachine.